# In a post build script how to check if the system is a 64 or 32 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shell, build-process, build-automation

In Visual Studio 2010, in a post build script, I need to copy one of these files to the "bin" dir:
myLib32.dll   or
myLib64.dll

depending on the architecture of my machine.

Is there a way to check in a script which architecture I'm using?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have $(PlatformName) available in the post-build command line, but that is the platform you have built it for, not necessarily the platform of the machine you are on.  Perhaps you can leverage the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable in windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to the project file of the project that needs the file, then I think it will do what you need:

It checks for the existence of the syswow64 version of program files - this is empty on 32 bit versions of windows

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OSBitness Condition="'$(ProgramW6432)' == ''">32</OSBitness>
    <OSBitness Condition="'$(ProgramW6432)' != ''">64</OSBitness>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <myLib Include="myLib$(OSBitness).dll" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(myLib)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```